# PhpMyAdmin browse tab disabled

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have made a website that uses a Login Page, Registration page, PHP and MySQL tables. My issue is that when a user registers it is successful (99% of the time) however, when they attempt to login, they cannot because of an error "login Failed". The reason for this is that in PHPmyAdmin, I am unable to approve them in my "users table" as the "browse" tab is grayed out/ disabled. Any ways to fix this/ enable the browse tab would be greatly accepted

Comment: It would help if you could show the SQL statement(s) and/or that part of code that it relates to . The issue I think is not with PHPMyAdmin .

Answer (score 2):

The Browse tab in PHPmyAdmin greys out when there is no data in the table. To solve the problem you need to check if your mysql queries are correct and if they don't produce any errors.